# SQL Server : Bad Request

Tags: sql-server, mobile, azure, service, request

I use Microsoft Azure Mobile Services and SQL Server objects. I have two tables "images" and "visited". When I try this in my script on Azure, I get "Bad Request" error. Why?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM images 
INNER JOIN visited ON images.url = visited.visitedimage
WHERE visited.visitorid <> "xhotsniperx"
```

Edit: the problem was ' instead of ". Thank you @SQLhint.com

Comment: Are you sure you are joining on the right fields ??? what other fields do you have in both tables ???

Comment: Also try using Column Names instead of `*`

Answer (score 1):

what about using ' instead of "